# C++ How can i create Object automatically via program directly

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor

Ok I searched for questions but couldn't get my answer, or was not using appropriate term.

```
if(choice == 2){
    string tempName, tempAddress; int tempNic,tempContact;
    cout << "\n\t\t*\tWelcome to Our Sponsor Registeration Section\t*\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter your name : "; cin>>tempName;
    cout << "Please enter your National Identity Card Number : "; cin>>tempNic;
    cout << "Please enter your Contact Number : "; cin>>tempContact;
    cout << "Please enter your Address : "; cin>>tempAddress;
    //  prototype Sponsor(string n, string add, int nic_n, int phone) constructor
    Sponsor (Constructor goes here) // how to make many objects now?
}
```

the code is pasted here https://codeshare.io/aVxl42

check line 69 where i am going to use a constructor to add the values, by this i can add 1 object, but what shall i do such that if a person who is using program wants to add more objects do it?

I know i need to encapsulate something between 61 and 70.
Please help me how i work this out.

Comment: Please include *relevant* code directly in the question body. If there are special line we should read, then mark them out with e.g. comments. Think what happens if the link goes away, that will make the question totally worthless. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to do, but Lists ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/ ) or vectors ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ ) of that specific object type might help.

Comment: Put the user input request in a loop and add the created Sponsors to a vector.

Comment: you can create an array of objects and then in a loop fill it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to make it loop? I'd suggest a while-loop.
I haven't used vectors in forever(professors forbid it) so I may make some mistake, but you'll get the overall point.

```
bool stop = false; //This is to check after each loop if it should continue or not
char contChoice;
vector<Sponsor> sponsors;

while(!stop){
    if(choice == 2){
        string tempName, tempAddress; int tempNic,tempContact;
        cout << "\n\t\t*\tWelcome to Our Sponsor Registeration Section\t*\n\n";
        cout << "Please enter your name : "; cin>>tempName;
        cout << "Please enter your National Identity Card Number : "; cin>>tempNic;
        cout << "Please enter your Contact Number : "; cin>>tempContact;
        cout << "Please enter your Address : "; cin>>tempAddress;
        //  prototype Sponsor(string n, string add, int nic_n, int phone) constructor
        sponsors.push_back(Sponsor(tempName, tempAddress, tempContact, tempNic)); 
        //Add whatever other arguments you want to pass in, in whatever order
        cout << "Do you want to continue? [Y/N]: "; cin>>contChoice;
        if(contChoice == 'N' || contChoice == 'n') 
              stop = true;
        else stop = false; //This isn't really necessary since it is false by default
    }
}
```

But I would also suggest that you make set-member functions in Sponsor at least. You can also use a dynamic array and make it expand, which is trickier than a vector, way trickier in fact.

Comment: Well i know where to put loop. but adding object into a vector was something new for me, and thats the point i was stuck where i want to add new object when an end user select option from the menu to add user, not predefined coded object actually.

Comment: @BaqarHussain Did it answer your question? Or is there still something you're wondering about?